# Typescript ///<reference path="...">: why doesn't it work for me?

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following files:

**main.ts:**

```
///<reference path="./external.ts"/>

hello();
```

**external.ts**

```
var hello = function() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

I compiled both files to javascript and ran them by the command: 
$ node main.js

I expected that function 'hello' will be invoked. But, no, I got an error:

> ReferenceError: hello is not defined

The tutorial about triple-slash directive (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) says that:

> The compiler performs a preprocessing pass on input files to resolve
>   all triple-slash reference directives. During this process, additional
>   files are added to the compilation.

so I don't understand why function from external.ts file cannot be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That aproach only works in the browser.  When using node you need to import (require) the file in order to use it.

You'll need to do this:

```
// external.ts
export var hello = function() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// main.ts

import { hello } from "./external";

hello();
```

Also, when compiling you'll need to compile it for node:

```
tsc -m commonjs ./main.ts
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in the browser. Do you know how to work it out in the browser?

Comment: In the browser you'll need to make sure that both scripts are loaded using the script tag, and make sure that `external.js` is loaded before 'main.js`

Comment: then I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Comment: When you compile it to the browser do not use `-m commonjs` or anything like that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying triple-slash directives only work in the browser. That's not true, in my experience. Or are you only saying the path directives don't work, but maybe other types do?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of reference file is to tell what's kinds of functions or types or interfaces available in the following program.

**It should be more about declaration rather than implementation.**

An easier example will be:
If in `main.ts`, you got:

```
console.log('hi')
```

Without `@types/node`, compile will fail, because compiler have no idea what console it is. That's the reason we include reference files for the compiler to pick up:

– Oh, there is a `console` object defined with the `log` method.

In your example, you can make declare in hello.d.ts:

```
declare function hello(): void;
```

then in hello.ts do

```
/// <reference path="./hello.d.ts" />

hello();
```

now you will see the compile succeed:

```
tsc hello.ts
```

This means the compiler is happy, it knows hello is a function and can be called like that.

However, if you run with

```
node hello.js
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

You will get ReferenceError, because **at runtime** node engine not implemented hello() function.
try use

```
console.log('hello')
```

which is implemented by engine will help understanding.