# Typescript ///<reference path=“…”> and "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following files:

**main.ts:**

```
///<reference path="./external.ts"/>

hello();
```

**external.ts**

```
var hello = function() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Inside the html file I put the statements:

```
 <script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I opened the browser with the html file, I expected that function 'hello' will be invoked, but no. I got the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

This question only looks like the previous question I posted: [Typescript ///<reference path="...">: why doesn't it work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638612/typescript-reference-path-why-doesnt-it-work-for-me/44639227#44639227)

But this time it treats the code in the browser, and not in the server side (as the previous question).

Comment: `exports is not defined` sounds like a syntax error, I'd double check and make sure wherever you are exporting that it says `export` not `exports`

Answer (score 1):

The two files with the contents mentioned work fine.

That said the error is most likely caused by *additional* code in the file along the lines of `export` or `import`. This makes the file a module and you need to use a module bundler (e.g. webpack) to use the generated JS in the browser.

## More

- [A webpack TypeScript quickstart](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html)

Comment: OK. So... what does ///<reference path="..."> do? Is it the same as "import" ? Why using ///<reference path=..."> and not import ?

Comment: `reference` only establishes the compilation context. Compilation context is better managed with a tsconfig.json https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html